# Need to manipulate results of line item with a code step in Zapier

Tags: zapier

[Screenshot of my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J7qT.png)

I have a python code step that returns a line item object with the names of some components, their component IDs and the allocation of the components (see screenshot)

Now I need to return ONLY the set of values where the component_allocation is greater than 1 and the name of the component contains "User"

In other words, for the data in the picture I want to return:

Component Name: Additional User, Enterprise, annual
Component Allocation: 5
Component ID: 587086

Are my commas in the component name going to make this impossible? I'm not great at coding (wild understatement) and I don't understand how line items work very well. I can ALMOST do this with a spreadsheet style formula step instead of a code step because it has line item support, but no FIND or SEARCH function to match the word "user"

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before. Luckily, you have control of the return in your Step 3 code step. I tackled it by:

1. Return a list of JSON strings rather than (or together with) a list of objects. Your return would look like:

```python
[
  '{"component_allocation": 0, "component_name": "Addition user, monthly", "component_id": 565257}', 
  '{"component_allocation": 5, "component_name": "Addition user, yearly", "component_id": 565258}', 
  '{"component_allocation": 25, "component_name": "Addition user, biennual", "component_id": 565259}'
]
```

2. Convert the JSON string to an object in your new code step.
3. Run you normal code now